# Why it is bad, that java.util.date is mutable?

Tags: java, date, jodatime, mutable, java.util.date

I've been reading about drawbacks of `java.util.date` for a while, but I can't understand why it is bad, that `java.util.date` is mutable?

Comment: For the same reason that it's bad for anything else to be mutable. Read any rant about purity by someone who's into Haskell.

Comment: I would say that all the classes that represent a mathematical value or a litteral should be immutable. We want to see them as values of an abstract type, not as objects that hold a state. It is useful to reuse the same object in various computations without side-effect, or to ensure a computation will never alter the state of the objects involved.

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate. The other question asks why Java Date API was designed this why, the current question asks why is this bad design. It is different.